# Tensorflow Equivalent of skimage.transform.warp or scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates

Tags: tensorflow

Does Tensorflow have an equivalent of [`skimage.transform.warp`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.warp) or [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html)? I am looking for some way to "warp an image according to a given coordinate transformation".

Ideally, this could be used as a generalized way of performing affine transformations on an image.

This is the [closest PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/781) I can find, and it is a much for the specialized version of this problem.

Here is [an example of these transforms](https://github.com/felixlaumon/nolearn_utils/blob/7b07c417bd0c636ab9b5f1179c9bfd9b3b1742cd/nolearn_utils/iterators.py#L165-L216) being used in nolearn.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [`tf.contrib.image.transform(images, transforms)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/transform) is exactly what I am looking for.